# Challenging DIY listening tests

Tags: discussion, resource-request

I'd like you guys to hit me with the most ridiculously hard *listening tests* (> C2 level) you are able conjure up from the depths of the Web. My criteria for a proper DIY listening test are as follows:

- audio or video, both formats are fine;
- subtitles or transcriptions should be available to check my understanding;
- a wide variety of accents is great, though I am focusing on British English accents specifically;
- the difficulty should come from range of vocabulary, unusual accents and/or fast speech rather than noise or other distractions.

I've been finding it hard to come up with free, "official" resources on the Internet that satisfy most of these requirements. However, from time to time I stumble across some real gems. As a good example, see [this](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=JygTwVsgx-c&list=LL&index=1) (the "translation" is in the comments); [this](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=jsUvcjk8J5c) other one is great and very funny but unfortunately lacks subtitles, so it's less suitable for my purposes.

Of course just spending time surfing the English-speaking part of YouTube does give a lot of exposure to a lot of hard to understand stuff. But perhaps someone is sitting on a nice playlist of exactly what I'm looking for and is willing to share.

Comment: Welcome to ELL! Unfortunately this question is off-topic on the main site, so I have migrated it here.

Comment: That movie you link to is not British English. Try Acorn TV....all British, with a few exceptions.

Comment: What movie? The second video is Irish, of course, but it's still fine. I accept samples from wherever, though I am focusing on British English. I'll look into Acorn TV, thank you!